# Subtracting and Update values from oracle database JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to update my 'Shares Issued' column here based on what a user inputs for number of shares desired.

Here is my table (which retrieves data from an oracle database) :

```
Share_ID    Company Shares Issued   Price Per Share
1           Google  4500000         871.52
2           Apple   2300000         403.2
3           IBM     3000000         195.07
4           Tesco   70000           326.5
5           Mcsft   850000          33.7
6           Dell    770000          13.43
7           Banks   100000          1440.4
8           SONY    650000          20.4
9           Marvel  20000           54.08
```

And I have the form here to input number of shares desired :

```
<form id="share_selection" action="buy_share_request" method="get">
    ...
    ...
    Amount of Shares <input type="text" size="9" name="shares_desired"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="   Buy   " name="submit">
</form>
```

What kind of update query could I write to subtract the user's input from the amount of shares issued in my database?

Comment: what is the meaning of # symbol in you query ?

Comment: UPDATE table_name set shares_issued = (Select shares_issued FROM table_name where share_id = ${share_name}) - ${shares_desired}

Comment: I can see more than one shares> How are you passing share_id ?

Comment: Would need a <select> or similar with a list of all the shares and the id would be associated with the <option> values i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would try something like this.(Not a full code just in general you would try like this)

```
int available_shares = select shares_issues from shares where shere_id=?
int remaining_shares = available_shares - Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("shares"));
```

sql query

```
updates shares set share_issued=remaining_shares where share_id=?
```